# Why does df.apply(pd.value_counts) "double count" booleans as both integer 1 (or 0) as well as True (or False), but depending on other integers in df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1
Out[19]: 
   c1     c2
0   2  False
1   3   True

df1.apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[20]: 
        c1   c2
False  NaN  1.0
True   NaN  1.0
2      1.0  NaN
3      1.0  NaN
```

Above is as expected.  (Each integer and each boolean is counted once.)

Now change the 3 to a 1 in column c1:

```
df2
Out[21]: 
   c1     c2
0   2  False
1   1   True

df2.apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[22]: 
        c1   c2
False  NaN  1.0
1      1.0  1.0
True   1.0  1.0
2      1.0  NaN
```

Note that the single True in column c2 is "double counted" as both True and as 1, because we now have a 1 elsewhere (i.e. in column c1).

So let's have a 0 as well as a 1 elsewhere and see whether False as well as True are both "double-counted":

```
df3
Out[23]: 
   c1     c2
0   0  False
1   1   True

df3.apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[24]: 
   c1  c2
1   1   1
0   1   1
```

Now it doesn't show True and False per se at all, and these values are being counted *only* as integers 1 and 0.  Why is this?

Let's add one new row to the dataframe with a value of 2 in c1:

```
df4
Out[25]: 
   c1     c2
0   0  False
1   1   True
2   2   True

df4.apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[26]: 
       c1   c2
0       1  1.0
False   1  1.0
1       1  2.0
True    1  2.0
2       1  NaN
```

Huh?  Now both the False and the two Trues are double-counted as 0 or 1, simply because we added a *different* integer (2).  Why?

Comment: I don't know what causes True and False to sometimes not appear, but since `True==1` and `False==0` in Python, it's no surprise that 1 and True or 0 and False count as each other.